# Is music store successful?

Tags: canonical, ubuntu-one

I am wondering how much money canonical gets from this store and some statistics (how much songs have been bought, ...)

Comment: This site is not managed by Canonical, please use one of their support contac ways http://www.canonical.com/about-canonical/contact to request such information.

Comment: I think it's reasonable for someone to ask this, someone from the Ubuntu One team should be given the chance to answer instead of just closing this.

Comment: I've got mixed feelings over questions like this :/

Comment: I am only curious, how is it successful

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The music store is one of our most successful offerings, so much so that we have expanded the related services, including music streaming to phones, and will continue to expand these and other related offerings in the future.